# How to create a train data for python chatterbot so that it can understand numeric values using ListTrainer

Tags: python, training-data, chatterbot

I am looking for a way to train the Python Chaterbot (https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#) on some numeric data so that it can understand the user input using ListTrainer.

Ex:
Bot : How many tickets do you need?
User: 500
Bot: thats a huge number. Sorry I cannot process that.

In the above scenario,  I can create a dialogue to make the bot understand that 500 is big number. But what if 510, 600 or any number, is there a way the bot can take custom decisions based upon a rule and reply the user.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: what are you using for creating the chatbot, dialog flow?

Comment: Chatterbot link :  https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#

Comment: Well, I have never work with it, but it seems a good chatbot. Reading the problem with the ListTrainer, it says you must train the chatbot with a list of strings where the order is equal to the normal respond of the conversation. It's like a train the chatbot with the rules.

Comment: So in your case, I should try the chatbot with the two list trainer cases, but maybe there is another simple and understandable way.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly the problem is that you want the chatbot to estimates when a number is big or small and gives a specific response. For me, the best option is to find the number in the string, modify it to integer and then compare it with the given variable. Chatterbot can manage mathematical evaluation if you use the MathematicalEvaluation logic adapter instead of BestMatch. I don't think there is an embedded way in the library to give a combined text with strings and numbers and let the chatbot do the trick